# Ubuntu Touch - Dekko email not opening browser link

Tags: ubuntu-touch, email, browser, email-client

When I receive an email with a browser hyper-link in it (such as a Facebook notification email), when I click on the link, the browser is not opening up. I click on the link and the "Open browser" confirmation box appears, but when I click OK, the browser is not opened.

I am not sure if this is a Dekko issue or if there are any settings in Touch that I need to turn on to allow the browser to open.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I have the same issue. I usually just copy the URL and paste it in the Browser. Not a fix, just a workaround.

Comment: I'm not sure this is an issue in Dekko as it just hands the url off to the desktop services which is then up to url-dispatcher to handle.

Is there any error output in dekko's log after trying to open a url?

Comment: I must admit that I had the same thought too. Thinking that it could bring something to do with the browser or Touch settings. I have checked in the Dekko log and it appears that it is unable to dispatch the URL. Errorlog output - process:6276): WARNING **: Unable to dispatch url 'dekko-imap://msg/2https://www.facebook.com/n/?find-frie=':GDBus.Error:com.canonical.URLDispatcher.BadURL: URL 'dekko-imap://msg/2https://www.facebook.com/n/?find-frie=' is not handleable by the URL Dispatcher
APPLICATION INACTIVE
QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread
APP SUSPENDED

Comment: I have not checked this on my phone yet, but when I get home tonight I will try it.

Comment: It only seems to be emails with links from facebook that cannot be opened. I had an email from a car parts supplier with a link in it. This link when clicked opened the browser page.

Comment: Links do not open on mobile either